# Homotopy equivalence of $S^{2} \vee S^1$ to $S^{2} \cup A$ where A is a line segment joining noth and south poles

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I have some problems trying to show homotopy equivalence of $S^{2} \vee S^1$(one-point union) to $S^{2} \cup A$ where $A$ is a line segment joining north and south poles of a sphere. I understand the general flow of the argument but can't actually construct the maps between the two spaces.

This question can be found in Bredon's Topology and Geometry Book Chapter 14 Exercise 1

Thanks!

Comment: Can you find an isotopy from one to the other?

Comment: This is shown in Chapter 1, Section 2, Example 2 of "Two Criteria for Homotopy Equivalence" in Hatcher. (Not sure about numbering since I'm looking at a hardcopy from 1999.) It uses the fact that if $(X,A)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property with $A$ contractible, then $X$ and $X/A$ are homotopy equivalent by the quotient map. This is proven in Prop 0.2. (Again, not sure of current numbering.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches

- If $(X,B)$ is a cofibered pair of spaces and $B$ is contractible, then the quotient map $X\to X/B$ is a homotopy equivalence. In your case, you could take $X=S^2\cup A$ and $B=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\mid x\ge0=y\}$. Since $S^2/B$ is homeomorphic to a $2$-sphere (which can be cumbersome to show), and $A/(A\cap B)$ is homeomorphic to a circle, $X/B$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ with a circle attached to it at the point $B$, and the quotient map $X\to X/B$ is the desired homotopy equivalence.
- The second approach presents a less difficult way: We regard $X$ as the sphere $S^2$ with an interval $A=[0,1]$ attached to it via the map $f:B=\{0,1\}\to S^2$ sending $0$ to the south pole and $1$ to the north pole. So $X$ is the pushout of the diagram $A\hookleftarrow B\xrightarrow f S^2$, written as $A\cup_f X$. Now $f$ is homotopic to the map $f_1:B\to\{(1,0,0)\}$, and since $(A,B)$ is cofibered, we can use the general fact that homotopic attaching maps $f\simeq f_1:B\to S^2$ give rise to homotopy equivalent pushouts $A\cup_f S^2$ and $A\cup_{f_1}S^2$, the later being $S^2\vee S^1$.

I think you can find the proofs for both facts in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, chapter 0. The proof for the second fact, also gives an idea of the homotopy equivalence implied by the setting.

Comment: What do you mean by "cofibered pair" and "cofibered?" I haven't seen this notions before..

Comment: @Vadim: A map $i:A\to X$ is a *cofibration* if, given a map $f:X\to Y$ and a homotopy $H_t:A\to Y$ with $fi=H_0$, there exists a homotopy $G_t:X\to Y$ such that $G_0=f$ and $G_ti=H_t$. In other words, a homotopy on $A$ extends to a homotopy on $X$ starting with the given map $f$. This is called the *homotopy extension property*. One can show that $i$ must be an embedding, so it's okay to regard $A$ as a subspace of $X$. We then call such a pair $(X,A)$ cofibered.

Comment: @Vadim: One can also show that a pair $(X,A)$ is cofibered if and only if $X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ is a retract of $X\times I$.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Now, it's all clear.